# PHP Array: changing values

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [menu_id] => 8
            [menu_children] => 0
            [menu_voce] => Eventi
            [menu_alias] => eventi
            [menu_pubblicato] => 1
            [pagine_id] => 6
            [pagine_titolo] => Pagina degli eventi
            [pagine_descrizione] => pagina eventi
            [pagine_testo] => <p>eventi</p>

            [pagine_creato] => 2013-12-04 18:49:49
            [pagine_template] => base.html
            [pagine_aggiornato] => 
            [pagine_timezone] => Europe/Rome
            [childs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [menu_id] => 9
                            [menu_children] => 8
                            [menu_voce] => Natale
                            [menu_alias] => natale
                            [menu_pubblicato] => 1
                            [pagine_id] => 7
                            [pagine_titolo] => natale 2013
                            [pagine_descrizione] => natale 2013
                            [pagine_testo] => <p>natale 2013!</p>

                            [pagine_creato] => 2013-12-04 19:09:57
                            [pagine_template] => base.html
                            [pagine_aggiornato] => 
                            [pagine_timezone] => Europe/Rome
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [menu_id] => 10
            [menu_children] => 0
            [menu_voce] => Promozioni
            [menu_alias] => promozioni
            [menu_pubblicato] => 1
            [pagine_id] => 8
            [pagine_titolo] => promozioni
            [pagine_descrizione] => promozioni
            [pagine_testo] => <p>promozioni</p>

            [pagine_creato] => 2013-12-04 19:17:37
            [pagine_template] => base.html
            [pagine_aggiornato] => 
            [pagine_timezone] => Europe/Rome
        )

)
```

I need to change the values in "pagine_aggiornato" == "pagine_creato" if "pagine_aggiornato" is empty, and after this i need to call a no-standard function.

In pseudo code:

```
 if $pageTree['pagine_aggiornato'] == ''
   {
      $pageTree['pagine_aggiornato']=localizzaData($pageTree['pagine_creato'],UTF);
   } else {
      $pageTree['pagine_aggiornato'] = localizzaData($pageTree['pagine_aggiornato'],UTF);
   }
```

The problem is that is it possible that exists a "Childs" subarray, depending if there is a submenu or not.

Could you please help me to write the smart and fast code to edit this array? Thank you

EDIT:

With the hint of umulder I'm using the array_walk_recursive, but I have every time the "pagine_aggiornato" value null.

This is code:

```
function _update_key_array(&$item,$key)
        {
            if ($key=='pagine_creato')
            {
                $creazione = $item;
                if($key=='pagine_aggiornato')
                {
                    if ($item=='')
                    {
                        $item = $creazione;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        array_walk_recursive($pageTree,'_update_key_array');
```

Comment: `array_walk_recursive`

Comment: function _update_key_array(&$item,$key)
  {
   if($key=='pagine_creato')
   {
    $item=$key['pagine_aggiornato'];
   }
  }
  array_walk_recursive($pageTree,'_update_key_array');     I don't know how done this..... In this mode I have error....

Comment: Solved changing the mode in wich I create array. By the way, thank you to u_mulder!